# I want to pass this value in to array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I want to add useeffect jobTitle and the noOfvacancy to the mydata array. my data array is dynamic and its size is automaticaly change using useeffect for loop.**

Finaly my target is pass data to display a pie chart

Image is attached below,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbqFQ.png)

```
useEffect(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < vacancy.length; i++) {
      var jobTitle = vacancy[i].jobTitle;
      var noOfVacancy = vacancy[i].noOfVacancy;
      console.log(jobTitle, noOfVacancy);
    }
  }, [vacancy]);

  const myData = [
    
    { x: "PHP", y: 90 },
    { x: "Python", y: 400 },
    { x: "Javascript", y: 300 },
  ];
```

Comment: Why don‘t you use useState hook?

Comment: @GabeRAMturn yes I use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to use `useState` like so

```
const [myData, setMyData] = useState([  
    { x: "PHP", y: 90 },
    { x: "Python", y: 400 },
    { x: "Javascript", y: 300 },
  ]);

useEffect(() => {
    const data = myData.slice();
    for (let i = 0; i < vacancy.length; i++) {
      var jobTitle = vacancy[i].jobTitle;
      var noOfVacancy = vacancy[i].noOfVacancy;
      data.push({x: jobTitle, y: noOfVacancy});
    }
    setMyData(data)
  }, [vacancy]);
```

Don't forget to import `useState`